# How to round up on a log10

Tags: go, math

This Go code gives me an error stating that operation `^` is not defined on a float64

```
10 ^math.Ceil(math.log10(5693440))
```

The number I'm passing to math.log10 is an int.  What am I doing wrong in this function? (Please note, I don't understand Math)

Note, if it helps provide clarity, I'm trying to create a function in Go that does something similar to d3.js scale.ticks() function, which creates values for a Y axis of a graph. The idea behind the above Go code is that I could divide the result of    `10 ^math.Ceil(math.log10(5693440))` by 5 and then multiply to create ticks for a Y axis of a graph

Comment: I don't know go, but don't you want math.Pow()? You could use nested ifs which would probably be much faster if you know the inputs range.

Comment: you can do that like this `num := 5693440
 rounded := math.Pow(10, math.Ceil(math.Log10(float64(num))))
 fmt.Println(rounded)`

Comment: `^` is not an exponentiation operator, it's a binary exclusive-or operator.

Comment: You need [`math.Pow`](https://pkg.go.dev/math#Pow) function: `math.Pow(10.0, math.Ceil(math.Log10(5693440.0)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `^` operator is documented in the Go spec under [Arithmetic_operators](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Arithmetic_operators) as

> ```
> ^    bitwise XOR            integers
> ```

This is neither exponentiation nor does it operate on floats.

Both [`math.Log10`](https://pkg.go.dev/math#Log10) and [`math.Ceil`](https://pkg.go.dev/math#Ceil) take a float64 and return a float64, so you are working with floats even if you think your argument to `math.Log10` is an integer (it is a constant so converted for you).

For exponentiation, use [**`math.Pow`**](https://pkg.go.dev/math#Pow):

> `func Pow(x, y float64) float64`
>
> Pow returns x**y, the base-x exponential of y.

i.e.

```
math.Pow(10, math.Ceil(math.Log10(5693440)))
```

Note that `math.Pow` returns a float64 as with the other math functions you used.